# operator precedence calculation and RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, calculator, operator-precedence

I want to ask help to figure out logic for **operator precedence calculation**.. 
At the moment I have code like this which can calculate only expressions with **"+"** or **"-"** signs.

```
string s = "100 + 50 -2*5*3";
string[] ss = new string[20];
ss = Regex.Split(s, "\\+|-|\\*");
MatchCollection sig = Regex.Matches(s, "\\+|-|\\*");
int x = int.Parse(ss[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < ss.Length; i++)
{
    if (sig[i - 1].ToString() == "+")
        x += int.Parse(ss[i]);
    else if (sig[i - 1].ToString() == "-") 
        x -= int.Parse(ss[i]);
} 

label1.Text = x.ToString();
```

So for now when calculating expression **100 + 50 - 2 * 5 * 3** I get 148.
How can I make to calculate at first **"*"** and **"/"** signs?

Comment: Check this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: This is a common problem. A little research and searching here on Stackoverflow or generally on the web should find lots of articles on handling operator precedence. You could also look for articles on "parsing" expressions. Krzysztof's idea of using Reverse Polish is good.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Take a look at the S[hunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and [operator associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). Also Google for [Arithmetic expression evaluator and C#](https://www.google.com/#q=arithmetic+expression+evaluation+C%23).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed in the same way you began :

You have to compute it in as much time as you have different symbols precedences and after each computing you replace the new value in the original sequence and you do it again with the lower precedence symbol.

```
original := "100+50-2*5*3"
precedance := {*, /, +, -}

for each precedance => P
    while there is a sub-calculation using P => C
        C := first sub-calculation using P
        compute C
        replace C in original
    enf for
end for
```